# Jupyter Notebook cannot show full wide images in mode %matplotlib notebook mode

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook to plot some wide images and I choose to use interactive mode:
%matplotlib notebook
It should have a slider at the bottom of the figure that allows me to slide to the right and left of the figure because it is too large. However, the slide is missing now and I cannot see the full picture right now like the attached image.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cBMr.png)

Comment: what matplotlib version are you using? This may be fixed in a more recent version, I'd first try updating to the latest maptlotlib version. You may also want to consider using the ipympl backend which will also wokr in jupyterlab https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl

Comment: for updating you can do `pip install --upgrade matplotlib`

Comment: @lanhi My matplotlib is 3.3.3 (up to date I think). I think this is not the problem of Matplotlib because I used to succeed in such a plot last week and it does not work for now.